# google.cloud.gcp_compute_backend_service setting securityPolicy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-compute-engine

I've tried to create a backendservice of gcp. The below ansible module is being used for that:

```
google.cloud.gcp_compute_backend_service
```

which is creating the backend service, but the `securitypolicy` is not assigned.

```
- name: create a global backend service
  google.cloud.gcp_compute_backend_service:
    name: test
    protocol: **
    load_balancing_scheme: EXTERNAL
    backends: **
    security_policy: armor_ssl_policy_1
    enable_cdn: no
    state: present
    project: test
    auth_kind: "serviceaccount"
    service_account_file: ouauthfile
    .
    .
    .
```

Not sure where am doing wrong, can someone please correct?

I've tried to pass string and selflink as well, no luck with them.

Comment: Just looking at the code you provided everything seems correct, can you share some error messages or logs ? Is the service being created at all ?

Comment: Thanks @Wojtek_B, we are not seeing any error response and backend is getting created, but the security policy is not getting attached,

Comment: How did you verify the lack of a policy ? Can you run `gcloud compute backend-services describe you-policy-name-here | grep security` and check if you're getting any results ? If there's nothing we can try to dig into Ansible then.

Comment: got the details.. security is not showing up

Comment: I was actually able to reproduce your issue - service gets created but with no policy assign regardles of the `security_policy` parameter. however you're trying to assign an SSL policy which can only be applied to frontends. Which policy you want to assign ??

Comment: its armor policy which i tried to assign @Wojtek_B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to [create a GCP backend service with Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/gcp_compute_backend_service_module.html) just as you did and I was successfull - however - the same thing happened - it was created without the [security policy](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview) assigned.

I already had an instance group and health check created beforehand so I focused on just a service; my `playbook` looked like this:

```
- name: Create Backend Service
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    service_account_file: /home/wb/key.json
    project: xxxx
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    scopes:
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute

  tasks:

   - name: create a backend service
     gcp_compute_backend_service:
         name: ansible-service
         security_policy: test-pol
         backends:
         - group: "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxx/zones/europe-central2-a/instan$
         health_checks:
         - "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxx/global/healthChecks/ssh-hc"
         enable_cdn: 'false'
         project: "{{ project }}"
         auth_kind: "{{ auth_kind }}"
         service_account_file: "{{ service_account_file }}"
         scopes: "{{ scopes }}"
         state: present
```

The service gets created but there's no security policy assigned.

`securityPolicy` parameter according to the Ansible documentation is a `string` type. I tried using ' and " - even a full GCP selfLink (for the policy) with absolutely no success nor the error message.

The only way (using CLI) that I found to remedy that is to run `gcloud compute backend-services update ansible-service --security-policy=test-pol` or try calling API directly (didn't try that yet).

At this point in my opinion there's an issue with ansible module calling the GCP API.

I'd recommend you to file issue on Google's [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) if some features doesn't work as you expected. You can also try [reporting this to Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/community/reporting_bugs_and_features.html#reporting-a-bug) team and reference the issue at IssueTracker (if you decide to report it) so they may even communicate during the process.

Comment: exactly.. its an issue with module @wojtek, i've google api to assign.. thanks for the support